# how to generateRandomTransform with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, random, homography

I tried to generate Random Homography Matrix that could be used to transform planar object image. It seems that opencv has a class "patchgenerator". But I can't find detailed information of this class. And some people said it only work with affine transformation. Is there some method to generated Random homography matrix? or I can use some OpenCV function directly? Many Thx!

Comment: Well, can't you just generate 16 random number and push them to cv::Mat?

Comment: yes, if i only need random matrix , maybe i can do  that. but i dont know how to get the random value area for 16 random numbers in order to rotated and translate the planar object image within some distance .

Comment: Look at this article:
http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm

If you only want to rotate and translate you would not need homography matrix. And with knowledge which element means what, you can easily limit the rotation and translation to desired bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a homography matrix by multiplying random scaling, translation and rotation matrices together:

```
H = T . S . R
```

The rotation matrix can be generated by using e.g. Euler angles (three parameter rotation).

The translation matrix is an identity matrix with last column entries corresponding to your point translation in each dimension.

Finally, the scale matrix has scaling entries for each dimension on its diagonal.

The final homography matrix **H** can be normalized by dividing it by its last entry (bottom right corner). You can check whether this entry is not too small (if you need 2D homography and project the transformed points in the same plane).

The advantage of this approach is a better control over your parameters (e.g. the translation corresponds to your typical translation amounts used) and the generated homographies are guaranteed to be invertible as long as the three simple matrices are invertible as well.

Of course, you can generate well-behaving homographies for a unit square, for example, and then scale the matrix to fit your actual problem (e.g. image size in pixels).

Answer (score 5):

This post explains how to generate random homographies from scratch - you have control over rotation, translation, shearing and projective distortion:

https://medium.com/uruvideo/dataset-augmentation-with-random-homographies-a8f4b44830d4

To briefly summarize the link above, a homography can be written as the multiplication of a euclidean transformation, an affine/shearing transformation and a projective transformation matrices.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please excerpt or explain the information contained in the link? Generally, answers need to have sufficient information to be understood independent of any links. Otherwise, they become useless if/when the link breaks or changes.

Comment: Affine transform matrix _Ha_ should have all `1` on the diagonal.

Comment: The affine matrix should have its (3,3) element equal to 1, not 0. Otherwise, if you multiply any point with this matrix, it would land to infinity after transformation. 

Ha = [[1, sy, 0],[[sx, 1, 0]],[0, 0 ,1]]

Answer (score -1):

Homography also has a shear and projective component. What you described is rather an Affine transform.